# Confirm output of spell checker before proceeding in bot framework

Tags: botframework

I am trying to accomplish this:

I have a spell checker in the middleware. In case the user's input text does not match the corrected text, I would like to confirm the corrected text with the user before proceeding. I tried several approaches but have not been able to achieve this. Here's the code I wrote:

app.js:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var restify = require('restify');
var spellService = require('./spell-service')

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});
// Create connector and listen for messages
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.beginDialog('search');
});

bot.dialog('search', [
  function (session, args, next) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Type the name of a company you would like to search');
  }
]);

//=========================================================
// Spell checker
//=========================================================

const dontCorrectIdentifier = "dontCorrect";

bot.use({
  botbuilder: function (session, next) {
    if (session.message.text.startsWith(dontCorrectIdentifier)) {
      session.message.text = session.message.text.replace(dontCorrectIdentifier, "");
      next();
    } else {
      spellService
          .getCorrectedText(session.message.text)
          .then(function (text) {
            if (session.message.text !== text) {
              var msg = new builder.Message(session)
                  .text("Did you mean \"" + text + "\"?")
                  .suggestedActions(builder.SuggestedActions.create(session, [
                        builder.CardAction.postBack(session, dontCorrectIdentifier + text, "Yes"),
                        builder.CardAction.postBack(session, dontCorrectIdentifier + session.message.text, "No")
                      ]
                  ));

              builder.Prompts.text(session, msg);
            }
            next();
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
            next();
          });
    }
  }
});
```

spell-service.js

```
// from https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56e73033cf5ff80c2008c679/operations/56e73036cf5ff81048ee6727
var request = require('request');

var SPELL_CHECK_API_URL = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/SpellCheck?mkt=en-US&mode=proof',
    SPELL_CHECK_API_KEY = 'MY KEY';

/**
 * Gets the correct spelling for the given text
 * @param {string} text The text to be corrected
 * @returns {Promise} Promise with corrected text if succeeded, error otherwise.
 */
exports.getCorrectedText = function (text) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (text) {
      var requestData = {
        url: SPELL_CHECK_API_URL,
        headers: {
          "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": SPELL_CHECK_API_KEY
        },
        form: {
          text: text
        },
        json: true
      };

      request.post(requestData, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else if (response.statusCode != 200) {
          reject(body);
        } else {
          var previousOffset = 0;
          var result = '';

          for (var i = 0; i < body.flaggedTokens.length; i++) {
            var element = body.flaggedTokens[i];

            // append the text from the previous offset to the current misspelled word offset
            result += text.substring(previousOffset, element.offset);

            // append the first suggested correction instead of the misspelled word
            result += element.suggestions[0].suggestion;

            // Increment the offset by the length of the misspelled word
            previousOffset = element.offset + element.token.length;
          }

          // Append the text after the last misspelled word.
          if (previousOffset < text.length) {
            result += text.substring(previousOffset);
          }

          resolve(result);
        }

      });
    } else {
      resolve(text);
    }
  })
};
```

Based on Gary's suggestion, here's the right way to do this:

```
bot.use({
  botbuilder: function (session, next) {
    if (session.message.text.startsWith(dontCorrectIdentifier)) {
      session.message.text = session.message.text.replace(dontCorrectIdentifier, "");
      next();
    } else {
      spellService
          .getCorrectedText(session.message.text)
          .then(function (text) {
            if (session.message.text !== text) {
              var msg = new builder.Message(session)
                  .text("Did you mean \"" + text + "\"?")
                  .suggestedActions(builder.SuggestedActions.create(session, [
                        builder.CardAction.postBack(session, dontCorrectIdentifier + text, "Yes"),
                        builder.CardAction.postBack(session, dontCorrectIdentifier + session.message.text, "No")
                      ]
                  ));

              session.send(msg);
            } else {
              next();
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
            next();
          });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the logic flow in the `builder` middle, which works fine on my side:

```
bot.use({
    botbuilder: (session, next) => {
        if (session.message.text.startsWith(dontCorrectIdentifier)) {
            session.message.text = session.message.text.replace(dontCorrectIdentifier, "");
            next();
        } else {
            var text = session.message.text;
            var msg = new builder.Message(session)
                .text("Did you mean \"" + text + "\"?")
                .suggestedActions(builder.SuggestedActions.create(session, [
                    builder.CardAction.postBack(session, dontCorrectIdentifier + text, "Yes"),
                    builder.CardAction.postBack(session, dontCorrectIdentifier + session.message.text, "No")
                ]));
            session.send(msg);
        }
    },
})
```

Use `session.send(msg);` replace `builder.Prompts.text(session, msg)`.
And remove `next()` in the else condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append **text** parameter in URL. I tried this in curl:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/SpellCheck?mkt=en-US&mode=proof&text=hollo%2Cwrld
```

The other thing is hyphen between spell and service in your .js file. You can probably try to check json response first to see if you are getting correction back.